# UPDATE on same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Why don't this work?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET `ns` = '0' WHERE `ns` = 1");
```

Help me please. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: OK, this is weird. I run this same code now after trying Adeel Mughal solution and it's now updated to 0. Don't know what happened? Thank you for everyone input :)

Comment: mysql is transparent about assigning a character value in an integer column, so you probably just need to quote the '1'. Just guessing tough, because of that little detail you put in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Tablename SET NS = 0 WHERE NS = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the `ns` column is being set to a string `0` instead of an integer `0`:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET `ns` = 0 WHERE `ns` = 1");
```

Check your column types and perhaps attach the error message you are getting to the question.

You can check the last error like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET `ns` = 0 WHERE `ns` = 1");

if (!$res){
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET `ns` = 0 WHERE `ns` = 1");
```

Please note that I have not quoted the 0, you were quoting 0 which would indicate it is a string instead of a numeric type

If that doesn't work then please give some more details as to the exact error returned